# 12.10 blank purple screen on startup dell Dimension 3000

Tags: 12.10, dell

I've installed 12.10 from a purchased disc. Setup went ok and I installed any updates. There was some error regarding something called "compliz" and I sent the error report. Now when I try to start Ubuntu I get a blank purple screen and cursor but nothing else happens. I have found and used the "change quiet splash to nomodeset" answer but this just ends up leaving me with a blank black screen. I am not very computer savvy so use words I can understand please:-)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said it's a Dell Dimension 3000 and currently running XP

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried this yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) I had the same issue with a Toshiba laptop recently and this helped me.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried these fixes now and they don't help. Any other ideas?